# Как включить бота для бесед вк написанном на php?

Tags: php

В общем скачал я тролль бота для бесед вк, но он в текстовом документе и написан на php. На том форуме было написано что надо указать свой токен и айди беседы, ну всё я так и сделал, но а также было сказано запустить его через php launcher и всё должно заработать, но мне выдаёт ошибку(на первом скрине видно). Помогите с решением. Если надо можем в дискорд пойти чтобы было понятнее.

[image: на скриншоте запустил через php launcher][image: сам документ как выглядит]

Comment: Укажите ошибку пожалуйста. !!

Comment: вы в программе задаёте пути до чего нибудь?

Comment: Нет, не до чего пути не задаю, только вставил этот php код из текстового документа туда.

Comment: Прикрепите пожалуйста код, спасибо.